# Azure CLI command to make changes to storage accounts

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli

I was looking to get help with writing an Azure CLI command to make changes to storage accounts:

- Storage accounts to use private link
- Storage account public access to be blocked
- Storage accounts should restrict network access using VNET rules
- Firewall and Private Endpoint should be configured on key vault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Storage accounts to use private link**

- To Set/Approve a private endpoint connection for the Azure Storage account, AZ CLI command is the `az storage accoount private-endpoint-connection approve`.
- To manage private-link resources on storage account, `az storage account private-link-resource`

---

> **Storage account public access to be blocked**

There are 2 types of public access to allow or disallow to the Azure Storage accounts:

- `--public-network-access`: Its values are `Disabled`, `Enabled` to the storage account.
- `--allow-blob-public-access`: Its values are `false`, `true` which does the functionality of public access to all blobs or containers in the storage account.

---

> **Storage accounts should restrict network access using VNET rules**

To allow the storage account within a specific address-range:

```
az storage account network-rule add -g myRg --account-name mystorageaccount --ip-address 23.45.1.0/24
```

To allow the access of storage account for a subnet:

```
az storage account network-rule add -g myRg --account-name mystorageaccount --vnet-name myvnet --subnet mysubnet
```

Note: `--subnet` means Name of ID or subnet. If name is supplied, `--vnet-name` (Name of a virtual network) must be supplied.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account/network-rule?view=azure-cli-latest) for more information.

---

> **Firewall and Private Endpoint should be configured on key vault**

There are plenty of AZ CLI commands on keyvault for approving, listing out, deleting, and managing the private-endpoint-connections like

```
az keyvault private-endpoint-connection

az keyvault private-endpoint-connection approve

az keyvault private-endpoint-connection delete

az keyvault private-endpoint-connection list

az keyvault private-endpoint-connection reject

az keyvault private-endpoint-connection show
```

To override the set firewall rules in the key Vault while creation or updating, use `az keyvault --public-network-access`, its values are `Disabled`, `Enabled`. This `--public-network-access` property is to specify whether the vault will accept traffic from public internet.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest) for more information on AZ key Vault commands.

**Note:** Complete list of [Azure CLI Commands on Storage Accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest)